# Generating structured HTML from JSON object

Tags: javascript, html, json, dynamically-generated

I'm trying to come up with the best way to generate a table from the below JSON object:

```
mytable=[
    {div:{
        nested:[
            {table:{
                nested:[
                    {thead:{
                        nested:[
                            {tr:{
                                nested:[
                                    {th:{}},
                                    {th:{}},
                                    {th:{}}
                                ]}}
                        ]
                    }},
                    {tbody:{}}
                ]}}
        ]}}
];
```

The end result would generate the HTML elements and be structured like so:

```
<div>
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th></th>
                <th></th>
                <th></th>
                <th></th>
                <th></th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody></tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

My logic is to check if the the object has the property `nested` if so generate the element and continue to loop, however I can't figure out how to do the bind the child elements back to the parents at the same time.

Comment: You dont need to return the table built inside the json. Just return the data and build the html with javascript

Comment: @VitorRigoni I know what your saying but thats not what I'm looking for, I want to use a more dynamic approach using a loop to speed up development.

Comment: Your `JSON` is not valid. You have a problem with your nested `th`. Plus, what have you tried?

Comment: Just an idea but you could turn your json into a xml (there are many tools for this) and you would have instant html :)

Comment: @cl3m nice catch sorry fixing now.

Comment: @YannChabot Haha yea I know, I wish I could but for this application I have to generate it from JSON.

Comment: Just use appendChild method and loop. Nothing complicated I think... Did you tried something yet?

Comment: Hi @JordanDavis I started writing something similar a couple of years ago, now is [here](https://github.com/fedeghe/widgzard), a bit evolved.
Maybe You can get a look and find the answer...In case is needed I'`m open to give all explanation. Hope it helps. :)

Comment: I can only guess what you might have meant by "binding child elements back to their parents". However, one option is to, as you're going through that JSON, store that JSON part's reference with each HTML element that you create. Note that you're not storing a complete copy of it, just a ref. Later, given an HTML element, you know where to find the JSON-part that it relates to, and then having that JSON-part, you can go up, down, left and right through it to find other parts (for example), or you can do the same walk through HTML. I can't know what your goals are...

Comment: Should `tbody` be parent of `tr` ?

Comment: @instead it's a little more complicated then that, needs to be structured.

Comment: @fedeghe I took a look, looks good but I need it in the above JSON structure if you could show me a pure JS way that would be awesome.

Comment: @guest271314 no the `<tr>` needs to go to the `<thead>` the `<tbody>` will be populated from the data that gets return on the server.

Comment: @JordanDavis ok,...but still I don't get the motivation for the `nested` isn't enough the json structure itself?... maybe You didn't decided it right.?.. ok

Comment: @fedeghe You would be right in saying that, however I will be binding `events`,`attributes`,`innerHTML` on to it as well, but for now I left those props out and am just focusing on getting the structure in the write format. so I will need a prop like `nested` to nest the children.

Comment: @h2015 my goal is to generate in HTML table like the example shows above from the static JSON object.

Comment: Good luck with that bud

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this does the work:

```
var mytable = /* your json */

function toHTML(j, n) {

    n = n || document.createDocumentFragment('div');
    for (var i = 0, o, l = j.length; i < l; i++) {
        for (var tag in j[i]) {
            o = document.createElement(tag);
            n.appendChild(o);
            'nested' in j[i][tag] && toHTML(j[i][tag].nested, o);
        }
    }
    return n;
}
var res = toHTML(mytable);

// now append it where needed
document.body.appendChild(res);
```

Comment: You sir are a beast! I love the shorthand to. If you live in the SF Bay Area and need a job we will def hire you :)

Comment: thx @JordanDavis, for the moment I'm ok in Switzerland...never say never! ;)

Comment: @fedeghe I'm looking for an OOP way to do the same thing but for server responses you got anything? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36581180/structuring-and-binding-server-responses?noredirect=1#comment60761612_36581180

Comment: @JordanDavis, since your question is a bit vague I refer to the link to the other one... I've worked a lot on that and the answer I gave here is just a hyperdistilled version of that https://github.com/fedeghe/widgzard ... worth a look, hope helps... Btw is not clear why You say 'for server responses'... Why should matter from where the json comes from?

Comment: @fedeghe I posted a link to the bottom of that comment

Comment: Sure, I refer to that when I say 'the link to the other one'

Comment: @fedeghe I read your .README file but it doesn't look like it handles responses.

Comment: The README does not help a lot... Sorry. I checked again your link trying to understand what you mean with server responses.... looks like you are just talking about xhr requests with fetch data in json that populates some models and most likely render into a subtree of dom. All that can be done with widgzard but you have provide xhr lib and use it in cb, init or end functions. Moreover another module shipped within widgzard is engy which allows for lazy loading of parametric components. If it sounds good for You I can make an example on the repo and let you know.

Comment: @fedeghe take a look at it now if you have some time, i got a 200 point bounty on it. I think only you and maybe a few others may be able to answer it, its a pretty advanced function.

Comment: @fedeghe haha thank you! prbly morning time over there, 12:30AM here so about to pass out but I'll be back on around 6AM (PST).