# Binding dynamic server response (nested json)

Tags: javascript, json, mongodb, data-binding, nosql

I'm attempting to build a dynamic data-binding function called `assemble` which takes (2) input parameters:

1. `server response (JSON)` - nested json object.
2. `instruction set (JSON)` - a configuration object which controls the binding.

---

***The Problem:*** The function currently doesn't bind nested json.

***The Question:*** What do I need to change to make it able to support the desired output?

---

***The current output:***

```
<form class="myForm">
    <div class="myFirstName">john</div>
    <div class="myLastName">doe</div>
    <div>john.doe@gmail.com</div>
    <div>this is a static inject element</div>
    <div class="myNestedContainer">
        //HERE IS MY PROBLEM
        //RETURNS undefined
        <span class="myUserAge">undefined</span>
        <span class="myUserDob">undefined</span>
        <span class="myRace">undefined</span>
    </div>
</form>
<form class="myForm">
    <div class="myFirstName">jane</div>
    <div class="myLastName">doe</div>
    <div>jane.doe@gmail.com</div>
    <div>this is a static inject element</div>
    <div class="myNestedContainer">
        //HERE IS MY PROBLEM
        //RETURNS undefined
        <span class="myUserAge">undefined</span>
        <span class="myUserDob">undefined</span>
        <span class="myRace">undefined</span>
    </div>
</form>
```

***The desired output:***

```
<form class="myForm">
    <div class="myFirstName">john</div>
    <div class="myLastName">doe</div>
    <div>john.doe@gmail.com</div>
    <div>this is a static inject element</div>
    <div class="myNestedContainer">
        <span class="myUserAge">26</span>
        <span class="myUserDob">1990</span>
        <span class="myRace">white</span>
    </div>
</form>
<form class="myForm">
    <div class="myFirstName">jane</div>
    <div class="myLastName">doe</div>
    <div>jane.doe@gmail.com</div>
    <div>this is a static inject element</div>
    <div class="myNestedContainer">
        <span class="myUserAge">25</span>
        <span class="myUserDob">1991</span>
        <span class="myRace">white</span>
    </div>
</form>
```

---

***The server response:***

```
response=[
    {
        first: "john",
        last: "doe",
        email: "john.doe@gmail.com",
        profile:{
            age: "26",
            dob: "1990",
            race: "white"
        }
    },
    {
        first: "jane",
        last: "doe",
        email: "jane.doe@gmail.com",
        profile:{
            age: "25",
            dob: "1991",
            race: "white"
        }
    }
]
```

***The instruction set:***

```
instruction={
    tag:"form",
    attributes:{"class":"myForm"},
    children:{
        first:{
            tag:"div",
            attributes:{"class":"myFirstName"},
            content: null
        },
        last:{
            tag:"div",
            attributes:{"class":"myLastName"},
            content: null
        },
        email:{
            tag:"div",
            content: null
        },
        myFakeTag:{
            tag:"div",
            content: "this is a static inject element"
        },
        profile:{
            tag:"div",
            attributes:{"class":"myNestedContainer"},
            children:{
                age:{
                    tag:"span",
                    attributes:{"class":"myUserAge"},
                    content: null
                },
                dob:{
                    tag:"span",
                    attributes:{"class":"myUserDob"},
                    content: null
                },
                race:{
                    tag:"span",
                    attributes:{"class":"myRace"},
                    content: null
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

***The assemble function:***

```
assemble=(data,instr)=>{
    var instr = (typeof instr !== "string") ? instr : instr.split('.').reduce((o,i)=>o[i], model);
    var n = new DocumentFragment();
    var gen=(d)=>{
        var o = d;
        return(_=(_instr,k,_n)=>{
            for(b in _instr){
                switch(b){
                    case "tag":
                        var tag = document.createElement(_instr[b]);
                        break;
                    case "attributes":
                        for(a in _instr[b]){
                            tag.setAttribute(a,_instr[b][a]);
                        }
                        break;
                    case "events":
                        for(a in _instr[b]){
                            _instr[b][a].forEach((l)=>{
                                tag.addEventListener(a,l);
                            });
                        }
                        break;
                    case "content":
                        tag.innerHTML = (_instr[b]===null) ? o[k] : _instr[b];
                        break;
                    case "children":
                        for(var _i in _instr[b]){
                            _(_instr.children[_i],_i,tag);
                        }
                        break;
                }
                !!_n && !!tag && _n.appendChild(tag);
            }
            return tag;
        })(instr, null);
    };
   (()=>{
       for(i in data){
           var test = gen(data[i]);
           n.appendChild(test);
       }
    })();
    return n;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end the only thing that changes is how you want the instructions to be used and extended. These are a bit different from the previous but one important thing is that the `appendChild` should not be **inside** the instructions attributes loop for the node but right after outside it; some attention must be payed to some special attributes as well,  maybe `class` is not the only one, who knows :)  ...
try to completely replace the inner `for block` with the following :

```
var tag = null, a;
if ('tag' in _instr) {
    tag = document.createElement(_instr.tag);

    if ('attributes' in _instr)
        for(a in _instr.attributes) {
            a.match(/^class$/) && (a = 'className');
            tag.setAttribute(a,_instr.attributes[a]);
        }

    if ('events' in _instr)
        for(a in _instr.events)
            tag.addEventListener(a,_instr.events[a], false);

    //
    // if ('content' in _instr && _instr.content!==null)
    //  tag.innerHTML = _instr.content;
    //
    // but take care ... what if is a input[text] 

    tag[_instr.tag=='input' ? 'value' : 'innerHTML'] = ('content' in _instr && _instr.content !== null) ? _instr.content : o[k];

    if ('children' in _instr)
        for(a in _instr.children)
            _(_instr.children[a], a, tag);

    !!_n && !!tag && _n.appendChild(tag);
}
```

==================

UPDATED

Now the output now is exactly the one expected. I even fixed a stupid bug handling the `class` attribute. Try it out, maybe even on other inputs, I tried to put text instead of null on some data and it looks fine. See You!

```
function assemble (data, instr) {
    var n = document.createDocumentFragment(), i;
    function create(d) {
        return (function _(_instr, _d, _key, _n) {
            var tag = null, i;
            if ('tag' in _instr) {
                tag = document.createElement(_instr.tag);

                tag.innerHTML = 'content' in _instr && !!_instr.content ? _instr.content : typeof _d == 'string' ? _d : '';

                if ('attributes' in _instr) 
                    for (i in _instr.attributes)
                        tag.setAttribute(i, _instr.attributes[i]);

                if ('events' in _instr)
                    for(i in _instr.events)
                        tag.addEventListener(i,_instr.events[i], false);

                //recur finally
                if ('children' in _instr) {
                    for (i in _instr.children){
                        _(_instr.children[i], _d[i], i, tag);
                    }
                }
                !!_n && _n.appendChild(tag);
            }
            return tag;
        })(instr, d, null);

    }
    return (function (){
        for (i in data) {
            n.appendChild(create(data[i]));
        }
        return n;
    })();
}
```

Comment: Ok I just copied that in and it's not putting any `innerHTML` in any of them. The way I had it originally just so your aware was `content: null` meant to use the `value` as in the current `prop: value`, I could also if I wanted to statically add a string in like this `content: 'my string'`, then lastly if I didn't want anything I wouldn't add the `content` prop at all.

Comment: What do you want as html?? The key??... just || k in the assignation

Comment: Yea the current `key:value`. When I console.log `o[k]` it gives exactly what I want but if its nest (sub-level) like how `age,dob,race` are then it just gives me the object.

Comment: To make the comment above more clear, an example would be, in the `response.user` object the `first` prop/key has the value `'john'` so if I add the `content` attribute with the value `null` in the `instruction.user` object,  with `null` meaning append the value "john".

Comment: I'll add a sample output to the question, one sec.

Comment: you did not, but was as the "bountyed one"

Comment: sorry thats what I meant to say.

Comment: Yea exactly. Sorry if I confused you.

Comment: Hihi no problem... You did not :) .  If I come to California you're in debt for a beer!!! See you

Comment: Haha ill owe you more than that lol. I'll def take you to dinner and drinks if you come, and or need a place to stay for a weekend your more than welcome.

Comment: Awesome.. See you!

Comment: Ok wait I don't think you saw the output above when I posted it, and then I said, "Yea exactly, sorry if I confused you". I thought you might of been working on it still and or busy at work or something, so just been waiting. Anyhow, I re-wrote the question so that it should be crystal clear now of the output I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: The reasoning behind this new post, is that the first version of the function you/we came up with works perfect with RDMBS, because RDMBS like MySQL "don't really" output arrays. I've been using NoSQL (which does output arrays) in a recent project for client and have been trying to modify the function now to support nested-json.

Comment: yeah actually I thought it was done... I take a look

Comment: Oh foreal, maybe I copied it in wrong... can you re-post with the full assemble function.

Comment: Ignore that last comment, sorry I thought you meant for me to take a look. Yea I revised the question to make it as clear as possible.

Comment: ok actually is quite simple, the only thing that was wrong is that, as far as one goes deeper has to pass refer to the deeper data object, then I added it in the params passed to the recurring function, I'm going to make a new answer, no STF wants me to edit my first answer, make a lot of sense :)

Comment: Damn nice already, Yea I was so close the other night, but got stuck. Your hella good at traversing functions lol.

Comment: Thanks again fed, you are the man! let me know if you ever decide on coming out here. Talk to you soon.

Comment: Great Jordan, if You have further problems or questions about this particular function feel free to contact me fedegheATgmailDOTcom. See You